# Using pouchdb in Ionic 2 RC.0

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, pouchdb

I am trying to adapt syncing data with pouchdb for Ionic 2 RC.0:
http://www.joshmorony.com/syncing-data-with-pouchdb-and-cloudant-in-ionic-2/for

I have installed pouchdb:

```
npm install pouchdb
```

Import it in `data.ts` file:

```
import pouchdb from 'pouchdb';
```

But I am unable to use it `this.db = new pouchdb('abc');`

Nothing is displaying on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did with PouchDB and Ionic 2 rc0.

`npm install --save pouchdb` to install PouchDB

`npm install --save @types/pouchdb` to install PouchDB typings

Then, in your code you have to import PouchDB:

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
```

To initialize your db:

```
this.db = new PouchDB( 'myDB', {adapter: 'websql'} );
```

If you need to synchronize your db with local CouchDB server (very useful to have a look at your PouchDB db content):

```
this.remote = 'http://localhost:5984/myDB';
let options = {
  live: true,
  retry: true,
  continuous: true
};
this.db.sync( this.remote, options );
```

If it still doesn't work, then try:

```
typings install --global --save dt~pouchdb dt~pouchdb-adapter-websql dt~pouchdb-browser dt~pouchdb-core dt~pouchdb-http dt~pouchdb-mapreduce dt~pouchdb-node dt~pouchdb-replication
```

Good luck to you, as Ionic 2 rc0 is a nightmare to compile (build) for now...

The Ionic team is working hard to solve compilation problems, but it still sucks...